# How can I alter next value of membership id (which would be auto incremented)?

Tags: civimember

I have an external identifier which has been imported and its max value is 10000,
 whereas it needs to be used as membership id, but membership id 
max value is 1500.Now to keep the Id of the membership consistent with 
external identifier, I want to start next membership id as 10001 
instead of 15001.
Is there a way to incrememt the membership id from 1500 to 10000 in database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more of mysql than CiviCRM. You will need to reset the AUTO_INCREMENT value for that table.

```
ALTER TABLE civicrm_membership AUTO_INCREMENT= 10001
```

Thanks
Pradeep